# Binding my local repository with an existing remote repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I am seeking a way out to cope with something in "git". Let me explain what I want.

I initialized a git repo in my local. let's call the folder name as "backoffice". I worked under this folder and committed changes.. with this

```
git init 

git add .   

git commit -m "login part completed"
```

Now, there is an existing repo in Gitlab. It is just initialized on the remote for me. I want to add my codes in my local into that remote repository and 
 then continue working under my "backoffice" folder. I will push the changes into that remote repository. How can I achieve this? Can you write all the steps as git commands if there is a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, there is an existing repo in Gitlab. It is just initialized on the remote for me

When the remote repository has been just created (without any commits), you can push your local branch directly to it:

```
git push ssh://<remote-host>/<remote-path> HEAD
```

When the remote repository contains files from a template (e.g. README) which you do **not** want to keep, you can do a force-push (`--force` option or `+HEAD`).

When policy does not allow a push-force, you can merge it with the `-s ours` strategy and push it as above:

```
git fetch ssh://<remote-host>/<remote-path>
git merge -s ours FETCH_HEAD
git push ssh://<remote-host>/<remote-path> HEAD
```

When you want a linear layout, you can rebase it

```
git fetch ssh://<remote-host>/<remote-path>
git rebase --onto FETCH_HEAD <branch-point>
```

or cherry-pick the commits.  Use e.g. `gitk` to find the `<branch-point>`.

Answer (score 2):

I would add the github repo as a remote, fetch, checkout the remote master branch from there and cherry-pick the revisions from your "old" branch.

Assuming your branch is called master and that it has 3 revisions, then:

```
git remote add gh url-of-gh-repo
git fetch gh
git checkout master
git branch -m old-master # rename branch
git checkout master gh/master # create new master
git cherry-pick old-master~2
git cherry-pick old-master~1
git cherry-pick old-master
git push gh master
```

Don't know if a cherry-pick saying old-master~4..old-master will work (nor a rebase). But doing it revision by revision should work.

Comment: That is, if you don't want to replace the remote branch with your branch.

Comment: No, I will continue working on that remote branch. So the first thing I should do is - "git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:yavuz/remote-repo.git" I will do that under my local repo, right?